# Is it possible to configure SharePoint app in the same domain as host web?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, dns

I have this task to create a SharePoint App without configuring a new domain or a sub domain in DNS as mentioned [here](http://sharepointchick.com/archive/2012/07/29/setting-up-your-app-domain-for-sharepoint-2013.aspx) .

Is there any workaround by which we can create the app in the same domain as host web. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The SharePoint-Hosted App infrastructure requires that each app be in its own domain for identification and isolation.

Instead of building an App you could build a Sandbox Solution with site pages and  JavaScript. It would give you effectively the same result without the need for the DNS changes.

Comment: Thanks for the help Rob. Same would apply for Provider Hosted apps too?